# Dockerfile post step

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have my base image which do common stuff - copies source code, installs requirements and so on.

```
FROM python AS base
COPY ./src ./src
(...)
```

And few images that uses it

```
FROM base AS dev
COPY ./requirements-dev.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
(...)
```

```
FROM base AS test
COPY ./requirements-test.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements-test.txt
(...)
```

Hovewer problem with this solution is that my test/dev requirements will install everytime when source code will change. I would like to inject somehow my dev/test steps between base image steps, so the cache could be used.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If your base image and your requirements do not change the layer should be cached.

Comment: That true in that case, but when src directory changes, then base image changes. And because this step is before dev/test steps, then dev/test requirements are reinstalled.

Comment: It the base image changes all steps have to be executed. That's how it is. Usually the actual source it the one thing that definitely does not go into the base image.

Comment: What's in the "dev" or "test" requirements that needs to go into an image?  Can you build one image with your normal `requirements.txt` file, and do local development and unit testing on a non-Docker virtual environment?